# ClassCastException: Same project works on different laptop with same JDK, IDC etc

Tags: java, eclipse

Recently, I have switched to a new laptop. The project(Java EE) which works on my old laptop, does not work on the new laptop. Ensured project version is the same, JDK is same, IDE is eclipse

But the project gives me ClassCastException on the new laptop.

(Both laptops are Mac, different model same OS)

The error is thrown by the library which is being used.

Stack Trace

````
SEVERE: The bean instance SomeCacheRetriever threw a system exception:java.lang.ClassCastException: com.api.client.AdminServiceClient cannot be cast to io..security.api.provider.AdminService
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.api.client.AdminServiceClient cannot be cast to io.security.api.provider.AdminService
    at io.evaluator.EvaluationServiceImpl.consumeManagedServices(EvaluationServiceImpl.java:249)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Feb 09, 2022 4:00:36 PM org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler destroyApplication
INFO: Undeploying app: /Users/AppName/target/app-1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
Feb 09, 2022 4:00:36 PM sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl invoke
SEVERE: ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy: 
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:826)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1627)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1607)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:763)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:2226)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1037)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:717)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1298)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1124)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5087)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1393)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)```
````

Comment: Something must be different, but since you haven't told us what the exact error message is there is not much we can do to help. Show us full stack traces.

Comment: Assuming you do `(CastTargetClass) obj`, check from where both are coming at runtime via `try { System.err.println(obj.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()); } catch (Throwable e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` and `try { System.err.println(CastTargetClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()); } catch (Throwable e) { e.printStackTrace(); }`. Probably you overlooked that the servers in which you run your code (or what do you mean by _Java EE_) differ.

Comment: Does your project work for others on their machine?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen yes. It works on my machine & many others.

Comment: Instead of moving the project, check it out again from scratch from version control.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen  yes, the project is checked out from git only.

Comment: This looks like a broken import.  `com.api.client.AdminServiceClient cannot be cast to io.security.api.provider.AdminService`